# Why is my StopWatch not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create a stopwatch that has a start button, a stop button and a pause button. I have so far reached start and stop buttons but the are not working. What is the issue. I have to even go ahead and create a pause button , how to do that. Please help.

```js
var seconds = 0,
  minutes = 0,
  hours = 0,
  timer;
var toStop = false;
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];

function start() {
  while (!toStop) {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
      seconds = 0;
      minutes++;
      if (minutes >= 60) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours++;

        if (hours >= 12) {
          hours = 0;
          toStop = true;
          stop();
        }
      }
    }


    document.getElementById("h").value = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" +
      (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" +
      (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    myTimer();
  }
}

function stop() {
  clearTimeout(myTimer());
  console.log(timer);
}

function myTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(start, 1000);
  console.log(timer);
}

function clear() {
  document.getElementById("h").value = "00:00:00";
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h"><time>00:00:00</time></h1>

<button onclick="myTimer()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
<button onclick="clear()">Clear</button>
```

Comment: [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/). Please take care when tagging future questions.

Comment: this part in your code `while (!toStop) {` is basically an infinite loop. This loop stops only after it has run for 12 hours straight.

Comment: In your `stop()` I would set `toStop=true;` and get rid of `clearTimeout`. Aren't stop and pause the same thing? maybe your `stop()` is really your pause, and your `clear()` is really your stop?

Comment: @ Thomas . After removing while loop , still the watch is not working

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Stop-Watch
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var myCounter;
        var seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0, timer;
        var toStop = false;
        var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];

        function start() {
            if (!toStop) {
                seconds++;
                if (seconds >= 60) {
                    seconds = 0;
                    minutes++;
                    if (minutes >= 60) {
                        minutes = 0;
                        hours++;

                        if (hours >= 12) {
                            hours = 0;
                            toStop = true;
                            stop();
                        }
                    }
                }


                var time = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" +
                    (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" +
                    (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
                document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = time;

                // myTimer();
            }
        }
        function stop() {
            toStop = true;
            clearInterval(myCounter);
        }

        function myTimer() {
            if (!toStop) {
                document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
                seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
            }
            clearInterval(myCounter);
            toStop = false;
            myCounter = setInterval(start, 1000);

        }
        function clearTime() {
            toStop = true;
            seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
            clearInterval(myCounter);
            document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
        }
    </script>
    <h1>
        <time id="h">00:00:00</time>
    </h1>

    <button onclick="myTimer()">Start</button>
    <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
    <button onclick="clearTime()">Clear</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I found a bug when you click several times **Start** it counting faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!toStop) {
```

Get rid of that. The `start()` func should just calc and print elapsed time. Also, don't call `myTimer();` in `start()`. You already call `setInterval()` which will call `start()` every second.

Instead of calculating the elapsed time the way you do, you should create a `Date` object in `myTimer()`. Then in `start()` create another one. To calc elapsed time, subtract one from the other.

And since you call `setInterval()` you should call `clearInterval()` to stop.

```js
var startTime = null;
var timer = null;
var totalTime = 0;

function getElapsedTime()
{
    var now = new Date();
    return (now - startTime) / 1000;
}

function start() {
    // Calculate elapsed time since start btn was hit
    var elapsedTime = getElapsedTime();

    // Add prev times (from pause)
    elapsedTime += totalTime;
  
    // elapsedTime is in seconds. Calc, h/m/s
    var hours = Math.floor(elapsedTime / (60 * 60));
    elapsedTime %= (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(elapsedTime / 60);
    elapsedTime %= 60;
    var seconds = Math.floor(elapsedTime);

    if (hours > 12) {
        stop();
    }
  
    // Build string
    var timeStr = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + 
        (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes + ":" +
        (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
  
    // Update timer
    document.getElementById("h").textContent = timeStr;
    document.getElementById("h").value = timeStr;
}

var amPaused = false;
function pause()
{
    if (amPaused) {
        amPaused = false;
        startTime = new Date();
        timer = setInterval(start, 1000);
    }
    else {
        amPaused = true;
        totalTime += getElapsedTime();
        if (timer) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
    }
}

function stop() {
    if (timer) {
       clearInterval(timer);
       timer = null;
    }
    amPaused = false;
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("stop").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("pause").disabled = true;
}

function myTimer() {
    stop();
    totalTime = 0;
    // Store the start time
    startTime = new Date();
    // Start the timer
    timer = setInterval(start, 1000);
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("stop").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("pause").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<h1><time id="h">00:00:00</time></h1>

<button onclick="myTimer()" id="start">&#9654;</button>
<button onclick="stop()" id="stop" disabled="true">&#9632;</button>
<button onclick="pause()" id="pause" disabled="true">&#9208;</button>
```

Comment: @Johnnny, after removing the while loop, still the code is not working

Comment: @java_jazz Your `time` does not have `id=h`. That's on the header.

Comment: @java_jazz Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: hi Johnny, i don't understand why are we using new Date(); when  Date() function gives - output - Thu Mar 08 2018 23:05:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: @java_jazz Using date is a more precise way to calculate the elapsed time. For example, if the timer doesn't fire at exactly one second intervals eventually your method will be off but mine will always be correct.  Note, the subtraction of 2 dates gives the time difference in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `while` or any loops they block io events, so there is no chance for the browser to update html.

If you like to use loops then you could try async/await:

```
async start() {
  while (!stop) {
    await sleep(1000)
    // some code to get elapsedTime
    render()
  }
}
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms)
  })
}
```

But I like to avoid to use loops for this task.

I believe it could be less coding and cleaner.

```js
const timer = {
  start() {
    this.time = new Date()
    clearInterval(this.interval)
    this.interval = setInterval(() => { this.tick() }, 1000)
  },
  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  },
  reset() {
    this.time = new Date()
    clearInterval(this.interval)
    this.render(0, 0, 0)
  },
  tick() {
    const now = new Date()
    const elapsedTime = new Date(now - this.time)
    const hours = elapsedTime.getUTCHours()
    const minutes = elapsedTime.getUTCMinutes()
    const seconds = elapsedTime.getUTCSeconds()
    if (hours >= 12) this.stop()
    this.render(hours, minutes, seconds)
  },
  render(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    const time = [hours, minutes, seconds].map(v => v.toString().padStart(2, `0`))
    const html = document.getElementById(`timer`)
    html.textContent = time.join(`:`)
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <time id="timer">00:00:00</time>
</h1>
<button onclick="timer.start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="timer.stop()">Stop</button>
<button onclick="timer.reset()">Reset</button>
```